# How do I get a regular Checkbox in a Zend Form?

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form

I have a form in Zend_Form that needs some checkboxes and I'd like them to be regular old checkboxes.  You know, you give em a name and a value.  If they are checked your post data contains name=>value.

Zend_Form is generating two inputs fields.  One, the checkbox with a `value=1` and the second a hidden input with a `value=2`.  Both have the same name.  I understand in theory how Zend expects the checkbox to work, but that's not how I expect it to work and it's not how I want it to work.  How do I get my old fashion HTML checkbox back?

I have tried using `$this->createElement`, `$this->addElement` and creating a `Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox` manually.  None allow me to set the checkbox's value and all generate the hidden input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html) is what you're looking for.

The standard Checkbox element is meant to represent "yes/no" scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

The final and REALLY correct answer is to add an option to the element :

```
$this->addElement('checkbox', 'my_element', array(
    'label' => 'My Element Label',
    'name' => 'my_element_name',
    'disableHidden' => true
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could **extend** Zend library and add your own custom **form element** to render it just like you expect it. I did it for having a date field and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why that does not work for you. You can set the values to anything you want (`setCheckedValue()` and `setUncheckedValue()`). So the only difference to normal checkbox is

```
if (null == $this->_getParam('checkbox', null)) {
//vs.
if ($unchecked == $this->_getParam('checkbox')) {
```

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I had already written the code expecting traditional HTML checkboxes, since the Zend manuals gave me no reason to suspect that anything else would be generated.  I didn't want to rewrite it.  The reason the Zend checkboxes didn't work is because in a normal check box a '0' value means that the value isn't set in the post data.  With a Zend checkbox it was set with a value of zero.  My code wanted unchecked boxes to be unset.  The multicheckbox solved it.

Comment: Try replace: "isset($_POST['checkboxName'])" with "isset($_POST['checkboxName']) && $_POST['checkboxName']" :) That's not that much of a work. Multicheckbox may not be suitable for all situations as it's group element! :)

Comment: I raised an issue on the Zend Framework issue tracker a while back covering the issue of the hidden field. http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6624 It's been a while now but you can still vote.